# Fail to get the specific dataValue from the return sequelize JSON object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two data models, one is Passport and the other one is Recipe, now I am working on one of the attributes in Recipe, which is called authorFbPage, and i am trying to get the specific dataValue from Passport, 
the code is

```
authorFbPage: {
      type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
      async get() {
        try {
          const thisUser = await this.getDataValue('UserId');
          let fbId = 'https://www.facebook.com/LabFnP';
          const User = await models.Passport.findAll({ where: { UserId: thisUser } });
          const Passport = await JSON.stringify(User);
          const PassportValue = await JSON.parse(Passport);
          console.log(PassportValue.provider);
          //The problem happened in here!
          return fbId;
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      },
    },
```

In the beginning, the User would be a huge sequelize return, so I tried to make it a JSON object, then I use JSON.parse to transfer it into below object

```
{ id: 2,
[0]   protocol: 'oauth2',
[0]   accessToken: null,
[0]   provider: 'google',
[0]   authority: null,
[0]   identifier: '109412096578527604841',
[0]   tokens: 'token',
[0]   salt: null,
[0]   createdAt: '2018-03-08T09:46:13.000Z',
[0]   updatedAt: '2018-03-08T09:46:13.000Z',
[0]   UserId: 61 }
```

and when I try to console the provider from this object, it returns "undefined", it really confused me since I already transfer it to an object, why it still won't get the value?

Comment: you need to add callback for findall method then assign passport and passportValue inside loop

Comment: Hi, but I already used the async and await, does that necessary to use the Promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using these much code : (Please read comment also)

```
const User = await models.Passport.findAll({ where: { UserId: thisUser } });
const Passport = await JSON.stringify(User); // remove await this is not async process
const PassportValue = await JSON.parse(Passport); // remove await this is not async process
```

---

**Solution :**

First change `findAll` to `findOne` as per the code I think you only need User object not array of object.

Just use `raw : true` , it will return json object with values only , no other extra stuff :

```
const User = await models.Passport.findOne({ raw : true , where: { UserId: thisUser } });
```

OR use `.toJSON()`

```
const User = await models.Passport.findOne({ where: { UserId: thisUser } });
const PassportValue = User.toJSON();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this recommendation, but when I console.log, it shows [Object Object], then I use JSON.stringify to transform it into a JSON object, but still, when I try to console.log  the provider, it still shows undefined

Comment: @yamahachou , yes it will show [Object Object] , in console but its the object , please check updated answer again change `findAll` to `findOne` and try again

Comment: Hi, it worked, I think you are the master of sequelize XDD, but based on my understanding, findAll can also return the thing I want, why we need to use findOne in this case?